# website is not picking up changes that are done in customize option

Tags: magento-1.9.3.2, customize

where is the path by which I can customize my website from backend in Magento?
it seems like frontend and backend have been disconnected there CSS file and so the changes are not appearing in the frontend. please help

Comment: Are you using any custom theme on your website?

Comment: yes i am using a customizable theme and its name is em-supertheme 0132.

Comment: the problem started when i first added custom css and after cearing the cache , when i went to frontend to preview changes all the colors , fonts and styling turned into greay and black since that time my webite is not picking up any changes i do on the backend in emtheme->stetting->customize

Comment: I think there must be some setting for changing color, background color, font etc. in the backend settings of the theme. First revert back the changes you have made in custom css.

Comment: yes i've removed that custom css but the settings for changing color and fonrs is still not displaying changes on frontend

Comment: I think you have not installed or configured the theme correctly. If you have billing details of the theme and your store is a fresh installation, then you can take support from their team.

Comment: Without checking the installation, it is hard to tell the solution of your query.

Comment: thanks mohit you helped me alot. but this was a free theme.